# Jetpack Compose: AnimatedImageVector not Animating

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

Please, I need help resolving this issue. I am trying to get a drawable vector to animate by rotating it. The drawable vector displays but it doesn't rotate as expected. Thanks in advance!

Below  are my code snippets:

This is my drawable vector file:
**loading_img.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="72"
    android:viewportWidth="72"
    android:width="24dp">

    <path android:fillColor="#cccccf"
        android:pathData="M36.06,28.92L36.06,32.18"
        android:strokeColor="#e7e7e7" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#c8c8cc"
        android:pathData="M39.45,29.88L37.82,32.71"
        android:strokeColor="#cacaca" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#bbbbbe"
        android:pathData="M42.12,32.32L39.3,33.95"
        android:strokeColor="#cdcdcd" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#b2b2b7"
        android:pathData="M39.8,35.98L43.06,35.98"
        android:strokeColor="#cbcbcb" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#d0d0d4"
        android:pathData="M32.77,29.99L34.4,32.81"
        android:strokeColor="#ededed" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#949497"
        android:pathData="M30.1,32.42L32.92,34.05"
        android:strokeColor="#525252" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#97979b"
        android:pathData="M32.42,35.98L29.16,35.98"
        android:strokeColor="#6e6e6e" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#a8a8ac"
        android:pathData="M36.06,43.08L36.06,39.82"
        android:strokeColor="#a0a0a0" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#cacaca"
        android:pathData="M39.7,41.99L38.07,39.16"
        android:strokeColor="#cacaca" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#b6b6ba"
        android:pathData="M42.19,39.4L39.37,37.77"
        android:strokeColor="#ccc" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#a1a1a5"
        android:pathData="M32.46,41.98L34.09,39.16"
        android:strokeColor="#909090" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#9d9da0"
        android:pathData="M29.85,39.4L32.67,37.77"
        android:strokeColor="#7a7a7a" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

This is the xml file to be animated:
**loading_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_img"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

This is my composable function:
**Composable Screen Code**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
@Composable
fun ProgressScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(modifier = modifier, color = colors.background) {
        val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.loading_animation)
        //var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .background(TransparentBlack)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            Image(
                painter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(image, true),
                contentDescription = "Loading Content",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = modifier
                    .background(color = colors.background)
                    .fillMaxSize(0.5f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the function `rememberAnimatedVectorPainter` is used to **finite animateion**, according to the document:

> To use an AnimatedVectorDrawable resource, load up the drawable file using animatedVectorResource and pass in a boolean to switch between the start and end state of your drawable.

In your case, the loading animation is an infinite one. So maybe just rotating the `Image` itself is better.

````kotlin
@Composable
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76025571/jetpack-compose-animatedimagevector-not-animating
fun Q76025571(
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val progress by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 360f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        )
    )
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.loading_img),
            contentDescription = "Loading Content",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = modifier
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                .fillMaxSize(0.5f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    rotationZ = progress
                }
        )
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks @FunnySaltyFish. It works. Funnily enough, I used this same code snippet before but my App was crashing. Seeing yours made me realize what I was doing wrong: ```loading_animation.xml``` instead of ```loading_img.xml```.

Comment: A quick question @FunnySaltyFish, I am using the aforementioned animated vector as a placeholder for images to indicate progress while the images are fetched from a remote server. The issue now is, when the images come and replace the animated vector, the images will be spinning as well. To prevent that, I reset ```targetValue``` to ```0F```. Does this have any performance implications? Though, I haven't noticed any for now.

Comment: I don't know clearly, neither. Maybe you can do more tests to see whether the anim is still running. Or maybe you can use two different `Image`, one for loading and another for displaying? (like `coil`'s implementation: [here](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#subcomposeasyncimage)